# Draw rectangle in flash actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to draw a rectangle in Flash when the mouse is held down.

Here is what I have for my code in the flash file:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var color:Number;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,startDrawing);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,stopDrawing);
function startDrawing(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, makeShapes);
    color = Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF;
}
function stopDrawing(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, makeShapes);
}

function makeShapes(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var rectangle:Rectangle = new Rectangle(10,10,color);
    addChild(rectangle);
    rectangle.x = mouseX;
    rectangle.y = mouseY;
}
```

Here is what I have in my actionscript 3.0 class:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip; 

    public class Rectangle extends MovieClip {

        public function Rectangle(w:Number=40,h:Number=40,color:Number=0xff0000) {
            graphics.beginFill(color);
            graphics.drawRectangle(0,0,w,h);
            graphics.endFill();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You might want to be careful with your code, there is already a class called `Rectangle` in the package `flash.geom`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to change was the code for the actionscript value

I changed this:

```
graphics.drawRectangle(0,0,w,h);
```

to this:

```
graphics.drawRect(10,10,10,10);
```